# Flexbox and images

Tags: html, css, flexbox, gallery

What I am trying to accomplish is creating a photo gallery using flexbox. I can get the images to align in two rows and four columns but my issue is I cannot manipulate the size of my images so they end up overlapping and looking terrible. I have no clue how to address the issue. I tried troubleshooting it myself for hours but I don't know the properties well to even have an educated guess.

Comment: Hi Kelsee, could you share some code using stack snippets? [How to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Adding some code would help understand what's really missing.

Anyway, I would try this:

```css
.image {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to assign width to the image you might want to set `flex: none` to the image.

```
img {
  flex: none;
  width: 33.33%; // or whatever
}
```

Additionally, if you're planning to have the images wrap to the next line if there's not enough space you'll need to set `flex-wrap: wrap` to the container.